# How to change the search criteria of auto complete text view in android

Tags: android

ive looked for an example that takes a autocompletetextview with a criteria of search diferent than "starts with", for example....
ive got this code :

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
  android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Autos);
  AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
  findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
  textView.setThreshold(2);
  textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the values of the array:

```
  private static final String[] Autos= new String[] {
     "porsche", "pontiac", "volkswagen", "algoconpoentremedio", "tricipo"
 };
```

i want to type "po" in the autocompleteview and i want to recieve : porsche, pontiac, algoconpoentremedio and tricipo, now iam getting only porsche and pontiac, so, what i want its to change the criteria from "starts with" to "contains", is this possible?, if possible an example would be great, since my english aint that good, when i read code in an example i get it way faster. thx in advance.